# Having an error trying to install cinnamon desktop

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I seem to be unable to install cinnamon desktop. I'm using Debian 9 (stretch), here is a screenshot of my terminal:
[image]

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Unable to locate" means the package couldn't be found in the repositories. And that's not how to install it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Install Cinnamon DE (or GUI) in Debian 9:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cinnamon
```

Reboot.

At the login screen, click the cog wheel to select a different environment, Cinnamon in this case, as shown in the image below:

[image]